# How to setup multiple views for one controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am making an app for basket tactics.The user can choose between multiple tactics and attribute a name for each players of the tactics.
[image]

I have more than 30 tactics. The only thing that change between each tactic is the position (x and y) of the players on the ground. A tactic is only a view with a background image and an UIViews for each player.
I would like to know what is the best way to manage each tactics (views) with the same controller.

Comment: is the tactic view presented by user choice ? or do u want to present all 30 tactics at once ?

Comment: create custom class of UIView and create its multiple object and add them as subview in self.view of your viewController,

Comment: Yes the tactic is presented by user choice. Then the user can tap on a player and attribute it a name @Mr.T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I would create them programatically by creating a subclass for your tactic view, that can be used to display all your different player positions.**

I would also recommend you create a subclass for your player views, as they seem to be identical apart from the label text and positioning. So first, you should create a `PlayerView` subclass:

```
class PlayerView : UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // do custom setup for the player view (add label etc)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Then you want to create a subclass for the `TacticView`. How you want to store your positions for each of the player views is completely up to you, but in this example, I've used a 2D swift array to represent them. You may well want to move them into a more manageable format (such as a `.plist` file).

You may also want to define them relative to the screen size, to save having to use constraints. For example `CGPoint(x: 0.3, y: 0.5)` (then you just have to multiply it by the screen size when setting the position).

```
class TacticView : UIView {

    let playerViewPositions : [[CGPoint]] = [ // store all your positions in a 2D array
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)], // tactic 0
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)], // tactic 1
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)], // etc
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)],
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)],
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)],
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)],
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)],
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)],
        [CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20), CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20)],
    ]

    var tacticIndex:Int = 0 {
        didSet { // reload views when the index value changes
            self.reloadViews()
        }
    }

    var playerArray = NSArray()

    convenience init(frame:CGRect, tacticIndex:Int) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.tacticIndex = tacticIndex
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // do further setup (add background etc)

        let arr = NSMutableArray()
        for _ in 0..<6 {
            let playerView = PlayerView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width:20, height:10)))
            arr.addObject(playerView)
            addSubview(playerView)
        }

        playerArray = arr.copy() as! NSArray

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func reloadViews() {
        for i in 0..<playerArray.count {
            let p = playerArray[i] as! PlayerView
            p.center = playerViewPositions[tacticIndex][i]
        }
    }

}
```

This subclass contains the array of your player views (the views themselves can be re-used across tactics, although you could initialise multiple tactic views if you don't want to re-use them).

It also allows you to change between the tactics though the `tacticIndex` property, that will change the positioning of the views to the given tactic index.

Finally, you want to initialise and add this to your main view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let tactic = TacticView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, tacticIndex:0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(tactic)

    }

    func changeTacticIndex(index:Int) {
        tactic.tacticIndex = index
    }

}
```

Comment: What about the position logic? I use to do my views with interface builder. What is the best way to define position of the views and their constraints?

Comment: I've clarified my answer a bit

Answer (score 1):

There are **A LOT** possibilities to achieve what you intend. One is:

1- Choose a persistence method for your tactics, because you need a place to store and/or retrieve the data. You can manage the position of the player views by any of the iOS persistence sources (CoreData, plist, fetch from JSON, etc...) is up to you depending of what do you intend to do with the final App.

2 - On your view Controller you can do either, load all 30 tactics at once on a NSArray or a NSDictionary (once again depending on what you wish to achieve).

3 - Represent the tactics on a tableView, CollectionView or any UI that the user can select on in specific.

4 - to present the tactics to the user, I think that the best approach is through CoreAnimation changing the position of the playersViews as the user selects different tactics. There are good tutorials of animation on http://www.raywenderlich.com.

Hope to help you find the best solution.